# Help understanding an incorrect "least counterexample" inductive proof.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fake-proofs

I am studying proofs by the principle of well-order.  Below is an exercise I encountered which I am having difficulty understanding.

> What is wrong with this "proof" of the following statement?
>
> For every positive integer n,the number n^2+n+1 is even.
>
> Proof:
>
> Let S be the subset of positive integers nn for which n^2+n+1 is odd. >Assume S is nonempty.
>
> Let m be its smallest element.
>
> Then m-1 doesnt belong to S, so (m-1)^2+(m-1)+1 is even.
>
> But (m-1)^2+(m-1)+1 = m^2-m+1 = (m^2+m+1)-2m,(m−1),so m^2+m+1 equals((m-1)^2+(m-1)+1)+2m, which is a sum of two even numbers, which is even.
>
> So m does not belong to S which is a contradiction. Therefore, S is empty, and the result follows.

I know from the beginning that the statement is wrong, it is false, therefore only a counterexample would be given. But I don't know why the page insists on proving it. What has me wondering is that by contradiction it assumes the opposite that n2+n+1 is odd, that is true. Therefore it begins to prove with (m-1) it does not belong to S and that is correct. It is one less than the minimum, obviously it is not in the set S.

This are my questions:

m2+m+1 is odd for all positive integers, so you could use mathematical induction instead of the principle of good order, because it is true for p=1 that expression will always give odd. I don't understand that part, it begins with a contradiction with the principle of good order, when n2+n+1 is odd, always the easiest thing to do with the principle of mathematical induction (I understand that you want to reach a contradiction).But why doing this stuff with a contradiction and the well order. The contradiction is always true. Dont know what contradiction I can get from a true statement
2. Is it valid if the statement at the begginig" m2+m+1 is even" is not true, to contradict it? I understood that only a counter-example has to be given and that's it, no more proof.

3. If you could contradict from the beginning that statement m2+m+1 is odd, always take whatever value it is and always give true, then how is it that you want to reach a contradiction, I don't understand.
4. The page says that the proof is wrong because m-1 is not a positive integer, as I said obviously it is not a positive integer, it is less than the smallest positive integer that the set S has, but this statement comes out of the following affirmation:
   m must be the next of some natural number (in the case that the proposition m2+m+1 is odd, it would have complied with m different from 1). That is, there exists k element of the positive integers such that m=k +1 then k=m-1. Where k does not belong to S and is a natural prior to m, then (m−1)2+(m−1)+1 must be even, when if I replace m with even or odd, this result will always give me odd in the two cases. Is that my contradiction? or the statement is actually wrong because m-1 is not a positive integer from the start.

Please help I am very confused.

Comment: Welcome. Please try to make the post a little more legible with MathJax and please do *not* yell in capslock. It is very rarely appropriate

Comment: In this exercise, you are given an incorrect proof and you're asked to show what's wrong with it.

Comment: YOU DON'T NEED TO SHOUT.

Comment: Doing a correct proof doesn't show us why an incorrect proof is wrong.  It only shows that the incorrect proof is wrong.  It doesn't show us *why*. ..... (And indeed, if we *can't* figure out why the incorrect proof is wrong, then we can't claim *our* proof actually is correct.  One must be wrong and unless we can say *why* one is wrong we can't say the other is right).

Comment: " I said obviously it is not a positive integer, it is less than the smallest positive integer that the set S has"  But if the smallest positive integer $S$ has is, say, $5$ then $m=5$ and $m-1 =4 $ and $m-1$ *is* a positive integer.

Comment: THANKS TO EVERYONE

Answer (score 2):

Okay,  this was meant to be an exercise in evaluating whether a proof is valid or not.

This is a proof that seems valid.  BUt it can't be because it reaches a wrong conclusion.  So it is asking you *where* did it go wrong.

You are essentially saying "Since we know it is wrong, we know it is invalid so we don't care where it went wrong".  But we *do* we have to be able to evaluate proofs, we have to be able to do *correct* proofs, so we have to be able to explain where an incorrect proof goes wrong, so we won't make mistakes in *our* proofs.

So we *have* to spot the error in the proof (which *must* exist as the proof is wrong).

Here the proof is correctly asserting $m$ is the minimum, and is correctly asserting that if $m-1$ exists as a natural number it would not be in the set.  And the rest of the proof follows *perfectly* that $n=m-1$ would mean $n^2 + n + 1$ is even and if so $(n+1)^2 + (n+1) + 1$ would be even and all would be even.

And note:  The prove said *assume* the set of $n^2 + n+1$ is odd is nonempty.  It (deliberately) never *showed* it was non empty.  And therefore this prove, which has only made *valid* statements, would have proven that the set $n^2 + n + 1$ is odd *is* empty by contradiction.

Obviously this proof is wrong but where?

And where is that although $m$ is the $m$ and $m-1$ **IF IT EXISTED** would be less than the min.  But it didn't take into account that $m$ could be (and is) equal to $0$ and $m-1$ (as a natural number) might *not* exist (and indeed it doesn't as $m-1 = 0-1$ is not a natural number.)

Comment: THANKS GREAT ANSWER

Answer (score -1):

To understand  the error in this [least counterexample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_counterexample) (aka [minimal criminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle))  descent argument it helps to first consider a correct such descent.

---

**Lemma** $ $ Let $\,f_{n,\,\ \color{#c00}{n\ge 1}}$ be an integer sequence with consecutive terms of equal parity $\,\color{#0a0}{f_k\equiv _2 f_{k+1}}$. Then they all have parity the same as the initial element, i.e. $\,f_n\equiv_2 f_1\,$ for all $\,n\ge 1$.

**Proof** $ $ If not then we can choose a counterexample of least index $\,\color{#c00}{k\ge 2},\,$ i.e.  $\,f_k \not\equiv_2 f_1.\,$ But this yields the contradiction that  $\,f_{k-1}$ is a smaller index counterexample by $\,\color{#0a0}{f_{k-1}\equiv_2 f_k}\not\equiv_2 f_1$ (note $\,\color{#c00}{k\ge 2}\Rightarrow k-1\ge 1$ so $f_k$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{well\ defined}$, i.e. it has $\rm\color{#c00}{\rm{index }\ge 1})$.

---

The problem with the quoted argument is that it fails to verify that the indices in the descent step remain positive, as we do above in the red text, i.e. $f_1$ is not a counterexample so the least indexed counterexample must have index $\,\color{#c00}{k\ge 2},\,$ so our decremented index $\,k-1\,$ remains positive (well-defined) in our descent step. Forgetting to check that is a descent analog of "forgetting to check the base case" in (ascent) inductive proofs. Note: it is simpler to use  $\,f_n = 2n+1\,$ vs. $n^2+n+1.$

In this case it is clearer to do the above proof in ascent (induction) form, using the induction hypothesis that consecutive terms have equal parity to lift the parity of $f_1$ up to all larger index $f_k$ (vs. push-down an  opposite parity counterexample till we descend to the contradiction that $f_1$ has opposite parity of itself).

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948742/242) for how to view (infinite) descent arguments as a contrapositive form of induction.

Comment: THANKS GREAT JOB. I APRECIATE IT

Comment: @̶A̶b̶r̶i̶l̶̶T̶h̶o̶m̶ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1855354/242) for another example.